# Javascript slider, How to assign a max value for scrolling so it doesn't overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I'm wanting to set a min and max value for scrolling that way it isn't possible to scroll beyond the content inside of the slider. Right now, the code allows for infinite scrolling. I'm fairly new to Javascript but I've been coding for several years at a University.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4Yjh/66/)

**JavaScript**

```
$('#vcards').width(function(){
var width = 0;                
$('.vcard').each(function(){
    width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
});
return width;
}());
$('#next').on('click',function(){
$('#vcards').animate({left : "-=170"});
});
$('#prev').on('click',function(){
$('#vcards').animate({left : "+=170"});
});
```

**CSS**

```
#slider{
width:500px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
height:225px;
padding:10px;
}  

.vcard{
width:150px;
margin: 0 10px;
height:200px;
float:left;
border:1px;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
background-color:green;
}  

#vcards{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:-170px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="slider">
 <div id="vcards">
    <div class="vcard">1</div>
    <div class="vcard">2</div>
    <div class="vcard">3</div>
    <div class="vcard">4</div>
    <div class="vcard">5</div>
 </div>
 </div>
<div id="next">Next</div>
<div id="prev">Prev</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('#next').on('click',function(){
    var v_offset = $('#vcards').offset();
    var v_width = $('#vcards').width();
    var left = v_offset.left;
    var total = v_width - Math.abs(left);
    var cont_w = $('#slider').width();
    if(total>=cont_w)
    $('#vcards').animate({left : "-=170"});
    });

$('#prev').on('click',function(){
    var v_offset = $('#vcards').offset();
    var left = v_offset.left;
    if(left<=0)
    $('#vcards').animate({left : "+=170"});
    });
```